# What happens when you bend a magnetic rod into a coiled spring?

Tags: electromagnetism

If one were to take a magnetic rod, and somehow neatly coil this magnetic rod into a spring in such a way that the former magnetic rod retained its magnetic qualities in the form of a spring (with the coils not in contact with each other), would there be a change in the magnetic field created by the former magnetic rod in its new coiled form? Brian Ghilliotti

Answer (score 0):

Great question. No clear answers but one can nibble on the edges. A toroidal transformer is almost the same with the magnetic north pole in a circle meeting the south pole in an endless circle.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toroidal_inductors_and_transformers

Comment: Another variable to consider is how much space is there between the coils of  this magnet rod reshaped into a spring. Perhaps the impacts on the magnetic field resulting from this magnetic rod reshaping will be partially influenced by the distance between the individual coils. What if the coils of this reshaped magnetic rod were in contact with each other?  “...the Ghilliotti coil...” Brian Ghilliotti

Comment: Besides distance between coils, there is also the variable of the diameter of the various coils of this reshaped magnetic rod...this is a thought experiment.

Comment: I plan to make such a system soon, using magnetizable steel. Will post the results as soon as I can. I will be as open as I can be, to discourage people from trying to "gain" from my findings. I am not a scientist, I will not be as technical in my language. I will be measuring the effects using an ohm meter and whatever mechanisms can be used to detect and measure magnetic fields. Maybe nothing unusual happens...

Answer (score 0):

I have two magnetic rods both with their north poles facing up. The force between the magnetic rods is repulsive. From this I will assume a  Ghilliotti coil will want to expand for a greater distance between the turns in the coil. An interesting point is a coil of wire with current going through it will do the opposite. It will want to contract for less space between the turns of the coil.

Comment: If I were to make a hypothesis, I suspect that coiling a "magnetic conductor", as I will call it for these purposes, will strengthen the power of the magnetic field (or in a weird way of looking at it 'magnetic current'). I could be wrong. I also suspect that we may detect some sort of electrical field within the coils. This is based on the belief that though flux lines will be strengthened by coiling, inevitably there will be flux lines that will be broken, yielding an electric charge. I am guessing this charge will concentrate mainly in the area inside the coils. Brian Ghilliotti

Comment: You can buy round magnets in a hobby story. They come in a package of 50 or so small round magnets. If you arrange them in a line they will stay that way with all north poles faces the same way. You now wrap this string of small magnetic marbles around a plastic tube. This would be very close to a Ghilliotti magnet.